# Removing Pairs of Reversal Transactions in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, transactions, data-cleaning

I have the following transaction data spanning three months January-February:

```
tab.m <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(1580947200, 1581033600, 1581120000,
1581206400, 1581292800, 1581379200, 1581465600, 1581552000, 1581638400,
1583798400, 1583884800, 1583971200, 1584057600, 1584144000, 1584230400,
1584316800, 1584403200, 1587168000, 1587254400, 1587340800, 1587427200,
1587513600, 1587600000, 1587686400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), Month = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3,
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), `Product Type` = c("LIZX",
"LIZX", "LIZX", "LIZX", "LIZX", "LIZX", "LIZX", "LIZX", "LIZX",
"LIZX", "LIZX", "LIZX", "LIZX", "LIZX", "LIZX", "LIZX", "LIZX",
"LIZX", "LIZX", "LIZX", "LIZX", "LIZX", "LIZX", "LIZX"), Account = c(931,
931, 931, 931, 931, 931, 931, 931, 931, 931, 931, 931, 931, 931,
931, 931, 931, 931, 931, 931, 931, 931, 931, 931), Subsidiary = c(124,
124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124,
124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 124), Description = c("Transaction",
"Transaction X", "Transaction", "Transaction", "Transaction X",
"Transaction", "Transaction", "Transaction", "Transaction", "Transaction",
"Transaction", "Transaction", "Transaction", "Transaction", "Transaction",
"Transaction", "Transaction", "Transaction", "Transaction", "Transaction",
"Transaction", "Transaction", "Transaction", "Transaction"),
    `Policy Number` = c(42057926, 42057926, 42057926, 42057926,
    42057926, 42057926, 42057926, 42057926, 42057926, 42060466,
    42060466, 42060466, 42060466, 42060466, 42060466, 42060466,
    42060466, 42060467, 42060467, 42060467, 42060467, 42060467,
    42060467, 42060467), Amount = c(10, -10, 20, -20, 30, 24,
    23, 22, -0.56, 1, -1, 2, -2, 2, 3, 4, -1, 3, -3, -3, -3,
    -3, -3, -3)), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = c("tbl_df",
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I have used the split() function to group the dataframe of transactions by month and policy number:

```
grouped = split(tab.m,list(tab.m$Month,tab.m$`Policy Number`))
```

Within each group, there are pairs of reversal transactions, where there is a positive/negative amount and another row before/after with the inverse of that exact same amount. I would like to remove these pairs of transactions from each group and thereafter merge the groups back into a dataframe. It may be that the positive transaction comes first and then a negative one, or vice versa.

Please note that the pairs of reversal transactions are not always adjacent.

Comment: There is a transaction of +3.00, then multiple transactions of -3.00. How can you identify which is the reversal?

Comment: It doesn't matter which one of the multiple -3.00 transactions is removed, just as long as a pair of them is removed.

Comment: And by pair I mean a pair of the -3 and +3 rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
tab.m %>% 
  group_by(Month,`Policy Number`) %>%
  mutate(id = rep(seq_along(rle(abs(Amount))$lengths),   #Create a temporary grouping id using run length encoding
                  times = rle(abs(Amount))$lengths)) %>% #such that sets of Amounts with the same absolute value are together
  group_by(Month,`Policy Number`,id) %>% #Group by this new temporary id
  mutate(temp = min(table(factor(sign(Amount),            #Create a new temporary value that calculates the number
                                 levels = c(-1,1))))) %>% #of positives and negatives, the minimum value of which can be removed
  group_by(Month,`Policy Number`, id, Amount) %>% #Group by id and Amount
  dplyr::filter(n() > temp) %>% #Filter out values less than the number to remove
  dplyr::select(-c(id,temp)) #Remove temporary columns
      id Date                Month `Product Type` Account Subsidiary Description   `Policy Number` Amount
   <int> <dttm>              <dbl> <chr>            <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>                   <dbl>  <dbl>
 1     3 2020-02-10 00:00:00     2 LIZX               931        124 Transaction X        42057926  30   
 2     4 2020-02-11 00:00:00     2 LIZX               931        124 Transaction          42057926  24   
 3     5 2020-02-12 00:00:00     2 LIZX               931        124 Transaction          42057926  23   
 4     6 2020-02-13 00:00:00     2 LIZX               931        124 Transaction          42057926  22   
 5     7 2020-02-14 00:00:00     2 LIZX               931        124 Transaction          42057926  -0.56
 6     2 2020-03-12 00:00:00     3 LIZX               931        124 Transaction          42060466   2   
 7     2 2020-03-14 00:00:00     3 LIZX               931        124 Transaction          42060466   2   
 8     3 2020-03-15 00:00:00     3 LIZX               931        124 Transaction          42060466   3   
 9     4 2020-03-16 00:00:00     3 LIZX               931        124 Transaction          42060466   4   
10     5 2020-03-17 00:00:00     3 LIZX               931        124 Transaction          42060466  -1   
11     1 2020-04-19 00:00:00     4 LIZX               931        124 Transaction          42060467  -3   
12     1 2020-04-20 00:00:00     4 LIZX               931        124 Transaction          42060467  -3   
13     1 2020-04-21 00:00:00     4 LIZX               931        124 Transaction          42060467  -3   
14     1 2020-04-22 00:00:00     4 LIZX               931        124 Transaction          42060467  -3   
15     1 2020-04-23 00:00:00     4 LIZX               931        124 Transaction          42060467  -3   
16     1 2020-04-24 00:00:00     4 LIZX               931        124 Transaction          42060467  -3
```

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for how I could use the above code to only apply to values of amount that are greater than 3? Fantastic answer, thank you!!

Comment: I beliebe your previous suggestion would filter out after the duplication. I was hoping to filter them before checking for duplicates, then applying the removal of duplication and binding the result of that to the filtered out data.

Comment: Right before the first `group_by` add `dplyr::filter(abs(Amount) > 3) %>%`. This will remove any rows where absolute value of the amount is less than 3.

Comment: Whilst this worked perfectly for that sample above, it seems to not work when there are other multiple pairs of reversals in one group (i.e. when grouped by month and policy number) having reviewed your code it seems it only removes one pair for each group?